# Archive Page for Single Category in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, categories, archive

I have two categories of posts on my site, for which I'd like to use the `archives.php` page.

I've already used it for REFERENCES.

I want to now use it for posts with a category of NEWS, but the customisations I've done for REFERENCES don't really work. Is there a way I can break to one archive page into two, or have a second `archives.php` page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Codex is **very useful**. That said:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

> In the case of categories, the hierarchy is fairly simple. For instance, suppose the slug of the Category in question is news and the Category ID is 6. The Template Hierarchy specifies that WordPress will use the first Template file it finds in your current Theme's directory from the following list:
>
> 1. category-slug.php (Note: available with Version 2.9)
> 2. category-ID.php
> 3. category.php
> 4. archive.php
> 5. index.php
>
> That is, if you do not have a category-slug.php (lets say category-news.php), WordPress will check for a category-ID.php (like category-6.php), and so on.